# InternetExplorerDriver gives strange error when instantiating

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I'm getting a strange error when trying to instant InternetExplorerDriver.  I've written the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Internet Explorer comes up, set to `http://--port=26290` like this:

[image: Internet Explorer behaving strangely]

It never ends up going to google as I've coded it to.

About ten seconds later, I get this stack trace in the console:
(TestBase.main(TestBase.java:358) is the line where I instantiate the driver.)

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: '4c5c0568b004f67810ee41c459549aa4b09c651e', time: '2014-02-19 11:13:01'
System info: host: 'LT10387', ip: '192.168.0.82', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:218)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:203)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:154)
    at com.gdit.fwa.informant.webui.base.selenium.TestBase.main(TestBase.java:358)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.40.0', revision: '4c5c0568b004f67810ee41c459549aa4b09c651e', time: '2014-02-19 11:13:01'
System info: host: 'LT10387', ip: '192.168.0.82', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:546)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:26290/status] to be available after 20002 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:163)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:79)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
    ... 10 more
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem exists here:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
```

This property is meant to be the location of the **IEDriver**, *not* IE itself:

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Download the IEDriver, place it in a reasonable place, and *that* location in that property.